# Preferences activity setting changes won't stick

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferenceactivity

I've logged maybe 6 hours so far fighting with Android preferences, including reviewing and trying many stackoverflow suggestions. My latest problem is that changes I make from my preferences activity aren't carrying over to my main activity. I have distilled the code.

Main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /*...*/

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        /*...*/
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.menu_settings:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, PrefsActivity.class));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("app_prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        int somePrefValue = prefs.getInt("somePrefKey", 1);
        /*...*/
    }
}
```

Preferences activity:

```
public class PrefsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.app_prefs);
    }
}
```

Preferences resource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Some Category">

        <EditTextPreference
            android:key="somePrefKey"
            android:title="Some Preference"
            android:defaultValue="1"
            android:numeric="integer" /> 

    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

In case it matters, I'm having this trouble in 4.1, both in the emulator and on a Nexus 7.

`<VENT>`For the record, here are the battles I have so far fought (and won) with preferences:

1. Where the XML preferences file goes in the Eclipse tree and what to
   call it.
2. How to force the preferences activity to restrict values to
   integers or floats.
3. That specifying a preference value as an
   integer or float in the XML does not make the preference an
   integer or float -- it's still a string.
4. That despite several methods
   taking the name of the shared preferences file, the only method that
   will actually load the file is addPreferencesFromResource(), only
   from PreferenceActivity. I have to code the defaults redundantly in
   the XML and in the first prefs getters, unless I parse the XML.

I had these problems despite reading the official Android documentation for preferences and despite reading the chapters on using preferences in three different books. Android documentation is generally pretty good, but considering my (continuing) trouble and the vast number of stackoverflow questions about this, I think this part needs some work.`</VENT>`

Thank you for any help you can provide with my latest problem.

P.S. I realize that the non-fragment approach is now deprecated, but I'm new to Android and have a tight deadline for producing a prototype that need not run on anything but my Nexus 7 tablet. I'd prefer it simple, though it's now looking like I didn't save any time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be using a non-default SharedPreferences in your main activity `"app_prefs"`, but your PreferenceActivity doesn't reference this, and is probably storing to the default SharedPreferences.

You should **either**:

1. Use the default SharedPreferences in the Main activity, instead of a named one: (also moving to onResume as suggested by louielouie)

   ```
   @Override
   public void onResume()
   {
       super.onResume();

       SharedPreferences prefs = 
          PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

       int somePrefValue = Integer.valueOf(prefs.getString("somePrefKey", "1"));
       /*...*/
   }
   ```

   **or**
2. Tell your PreferenceActivity the name of the SharedPreferences you want to use:

   ```
   public class PrefsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName("app_prefs"); //ADD ME
           addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.app_prefs);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you Tim. I made exactly the changes you suggested, but I still have the same problem. Do I need to do something else too? I'm not seeing how the preference activity is loading into the default shared preferences.

Comment: @JoeLapp Which change did you make, #1 or #2? You shouldn't do them both. I would recommend just going always with default shared preferences, not named. Also I think you may have a problem in that your PreferenceActivity is probably storing somePrefKey as a `String`, not an `int`. So you should use `prefs.getString("somePrefKey", "1");` instead.

Comment: @JoeLapp *"I'm not seeing how the preference activity is loading into the default shared preferences."*, This should happen automatically in the PreferenceActivity. As soon as you change anything in the activity it should be automatically committed to the default preferences file.

Comment: Tim makes a good point.  I always use option #1, i.e. I always use SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

Comment: Oh, I missed your "OR". I was doing both. I just now made only change #1 and now I'm dealing with an Integer casting problem, even after switching over to getString() and not getInt(). I suspect I'm on the road to getting this working now. Gimme a moment to look into this new problem. Thank you!

Comment: It's working! My casting problem is with the next preference I'm reading, which must somehow be residual from a previous debugging session. Woohoo!!! The preference I set in the preference activity is now carrying over to the main activity. THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: @JoeLapp Glad to help. Please make sure to tick the checkmark next to the answer if your problem is solved to your satisfaction, so that the question does not remain unanswered.

Comment: Yes, I was planning to do that -- just wanted to eliminate my integer problem to make sure everything is really working. It's all cleaned up now, everything works as expected. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue with that code snippet is that you are using onStart, which may not get called when you go to the PrefsActivity and then back to the MainActivity.
Instead, you want to use onResume() like so:

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("app_prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    int somePrefValue = prefs.getInt("somePrefKey", 1);
    /*...*/
}
```

onResume will definitely be called when you go back to the MainActivity.

The lifecycle diagram at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle illustrates this well.

Comment: Thanks Luis. I should have mentioned that my onStart() is also writing to an on-screen log of the main activity, so I can see each return from the preferences activity being logged with a new call to onStart(). Just for grins, I moved it over to onResume(), but no change. So, if the problem isn't glaring, I wonder if it's an OS thing. I'll try a different emulator...

Comment: BTW, that is a nice diagram, but the book _Android 4 Application Development_ by Reto Meier has an even clearer diagram. It makes it clear that the onStart()...onStop() sequence brackets a session of the activity being visible. If the activity ceases to be visible and is made visible again, onStart() gets called, as my logs are showing. onResume() is probably more robust for my purposes though.